# UIImage for UIImageView is nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I'm having problem displaying UIImage in UIImageView. I looked all over stackoverflow for similar questions, but none of the fixes helped me.

1. The image is indeed in my bundle
2. File Inspector -> Target Membership is checked for the image
3. IBOutlet is connected (I have tried both using IBOutlet and doing it programmatically)
4. Both png nor jpg works

Here's the code for using Interface Builder -

```
//@property and @synthesize set for IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSAssert(self.imageView, @"self.imageView is nil. Check your IBOutlet connection");
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.jpg"];
        NSAssert(image, @"image is nil");
        self.imageView.image = image;      
    }
```

This code will terminate with NSAssert, printing in the console that 'image is nil'.

I also tried selecting the Image directly from the attributes inspector:
[image]

However it still doesn't show the image (still terminates with NSAssert - 'image is nil').

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the image for your image view before testing whether it is nil

Comment: did you add your image to the target?

Comment: @geraldWilliam Tried it, didn't work...

Comment: @NeverBe Yes, image was added to the target

Comment: May be you mixed up file extensions jpg <-> png

Comment: How do you know the image is in the bundle? Do you mean its in your project, or did you really look in the bundle? If you know how to use Terminal, go to the folder where you have the image, and do a 'echo ban*' | od -c' and make sure there are no odd Unicode chars or spaces in the filename, or appended to the '.jpg'.

Comment: show file image name from files tree. May be it is Banner.jpg, not banner.jpg

Comment: @DavidH I did what you suggested in the terminal. There are no odd Unicode chars nor spaces in the filename. I am also certain that the image is in the bundle because when I go to Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, the "banner.jpg" is there.

Comment: @NeverBe yeah, I doubled check the spelling and upper/lower case. There shouldn't be a problem there...also it doesn't matter if it's jpg nor png, I tried both already.

Comment: Image maybe corrupt, try another one

Comment: See if you can get see the file in your code - use path = [[NSBundle main bundle] pathForResource:@"banner" ofType:@"jpg"]; assert(path); [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExists:path]'. I just typed this in but you get the idea - get the path using the first, make sure you got it, then ask the file manager to see if it exists. If it does you can read the file into a NSData object, then log the size, then see if you can create the image using imageWithData - if that fails then iOS may not be able to decompress it.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, it seems like the size of the image was causing the issue. I decreased the image size from 240KB to 50KB and it now works fine. I'd like to choose your comment as best answer but I'm not sure on how to do that....

Comment: @NeverBe I don't think the image file was corrupted. I tried numerous valid images that would open in other editors (Preview, Photoshop, Paintbrush etc). However, they were unable to be opened in XCode because the file size is too big. Your suggestion did made me think that it was something to do with the image. However it wasn't corrupted, just not supported I guess. I do really appreciate all of your feedbacks though!

Comment: native iOS framework can open files about 1-3MB and more. You have just 250kb. File can opens in other editors but in app not

Comment: @NeverBe you suggested the image was corrupted, which implies I should change images. And I did. That did not solve the problem. DavidH suggested it has to do with the size of the image. I made the image smaller and it worked.

Comment: Size can affect only memory consumption and perfomance.

Comment: Size should not be the problem, I often load images way heavier than that. Anyway, Xcode bugs sometimes, closing and reloading it can solve some weird problems, along with a clean build, or re-install the app completely in the simulator/device.

Comment: It cannot be a problem with file size. It could be a problem with too many pixels, though unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get see the file in your code - use

```
path = [[NSBundle main bundle] pathForResource:@"banner" ofType:@"jpg"];
assert(path); 
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExists:path])
```

I just typed this in but you get the idea - get the path using the first, make sure you got it, then ask the file manager to see if it exists. If it does you can read the file into a NSData object, then log the size, then see if you can create the image using imageWithData - if that fails then iOS may not be able to decompress it.

I often take images created in PhotoShop or elsewhere, load them in Preview, then save them before adding them to my projects. In general, if an Apple technology saves the image in whatever format you want (png, jpg, etc), then its likely that iOS can open it too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in the comment section for the question. It solved the problem I was having. If you can edit this post and put that comment here I will accept it as the best answer. Thanks.